# Nodejs | unzip and read only top n lines of files

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, unzip, nodejs-stream

I have a zip in s3 which has hundreds of csv files. I am trying to stream the files and need to read the top n lines of the file. I am able to unzip it and read the content but not sure how to stop the stream when I am done reading n lines and carry on with rest of the files.

Code tried so far

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const etl = require("etl");
const unzip = require("unzip-stream");

function setupMetadata() {
  s3.getObject({Bucket: 'test', Key: 'CSV.zip'}).createReadStream()
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', function (entry) {
      var i = 0;
      var recordIdentifier;
      entry
      .pipe(etl.map(res => {
        if (recordIdentifier) {
          console.log(recordIdentifier);
          console.log(i++);
          // not sure about this. THis works but it only works for 1st file
          // after that the program terminates. I need to do that for all the
          // files in the zip
          entry.destroy(); 
        }
        const data = res.toString("utf-8");
        var array = data.toString().split("\n");
        if(array.length >= 3) {
          recordIdentifier = array[2].split(",")[0];
        }
      }))
    })
}

setupMetadata();
```

I have tried calling `entry.autodrain()` after reading the content but it doesn't work. `entry.destroy()` works but the program terminates after that.I want to do the same for all the files in the zip.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to replicate a similar case. I hope you require something like this:

```
const etl = require("etl");
const unzip = require("unzip-stream");
const fs = require('fs');

function readRecord(entry, entNum) {

    let recordCount = 0;
    let etlcsv = entry.pipe(etl.csv())
    etlcsv.pipe(etl.map(d => {
        console.log(d);
        recordCount++;
        if (recordCount > 2) {
            etlcsv.destroy()
            entry.autodrain();
        }
    }))
}

function setupMetadata() {
    let entryCount = 0;
    let ent = {}

    let test = fs.createReadStream('csv.zip').pipe(unzip.Parse())
    test.on('entry', function(entry) {
        entryCount++;
        console.log(entryCount)
        readRecord(entry, entryCount)
    })

}

setupMetadata()
```

Check this REPL for test: https://repl.it/@sandeepp2016/PlushFatherlyMonotone

Comment: Thanks @sandeep - With your version I managed to make it work. I have made a small change in your code. Basically instead of `entry.destroy();`, i changed it to `entry.autodrain();`

Comment: @AshishModi - I am glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

I've done something a bit similar to this, using got.

I've had to adapt the code so it's not tested, but this general approach worked for me. I've not used etl so I'm not sure how it handles chunks of files rather than whole files.

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const got = require('got');
const etl = require("etl");


const getAllFilesAsUrls = async(bucket_name, folder_name) => {

    const listParams = {
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Delimiter: '/',
        StartAfter: `${folder_name}/`
    };

    const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();

    const keys = data.Contents.map(object => object.key);

    const urlsArray = [];

    for (let key of keys) {

        const params = {Bucket: bucket_name, Key: key};
        let url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params).promise();
        urlsArray.push(url);

    }

    return urlsArray;


}

workEachFileUrl = (url) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //if you're looking to limit the amount of data transferred then this was a good way of doing it
        const gotstream = got.stream(url, { headers: { "accept-encoding": "gzip" } })
            .on('data', (chunk) => {
                //pause the stream as soon as we get the first chunk
                gotstream.pause();
                //do your work with the chunk, as long as etl can handle partial files, then resolve with the first few lines
                //otherwise just use the 'response' event as you were with                     const parsedChunk;
                resolve(parsedChunk);
            })
            .on("error", (err) => {    
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            });
    });

}

runOperation = async (bucket_name, folder_name) => {

    const records = [];

    const urls = await getAllFilesAsUrls(bucket_name, folder_name);

    for (let url of urls) {

        let record = await workEachFileUrl(url);
        records.push(record);

    }

    return records;

}

const completedRecords = await runOperation(bucket_name, folder_name);
```